# How to run PythonTeX

Tags: compiling, mac, python, pythontex

I've been trying to get PythonTeX up and running on my system (Mac running Catalina) but it's not working and I can't figure out why. I think it's something to do with the fact that it doesn't create or run an actual `.py` file but I'm not sure. I'll include the code I'm running below. The important thing is that I can't find any step-by-step walkthrough on how to install it or make it work. All the below code does is print the em dash and not the python result. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
---
\begin{pycode}
print("we're no strangers to love")
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

Edit: ok I tried the solution that @Nasser used but I got the following error in the console:

```
No file pythontex-files-Untitled-3/Untitled-3.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Untitled-3.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Untitled-3.pdf (1 page, 8416 bytes).
Transcript written on Untitled-3.log.
```

And again it only printed the —.